# How to get records from a table if it does not exist in another related table laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I have two tables

```
tb_teachers
-----------
id
name
school_id

tb_class_to_teachers
--------------------
id
teacher_id
class_id
assigned_status
school_id
```

How to get records from tb_teachers if it(teacher_id and school_id) does not exist in another related table tb_class_to_teachers using laravel query builder

Comment: *How to get records from tb_teachers if it(teacher_id and school_id) does not exist in another related table tb_class_to_teachers* are you asking for any teacher or class that not assigned to class (for teachers) or teacher (for classes)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you set up your relationship correctly, then u may use `doesntHave`

```
$teachers = App\Teachers::doesntHave('class')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$classToTeachers = DB::table('tb_class_to_teachers')->get();
        if($classToTeachers->teacher_id == null && $classToTeachers->school_id == null)
        {
            $teacher = DB::table('tb_teachers')->get();
        }
```

Comment: it's not working ..Property [teacher_id] does not exist on this collection instance